# Question about function returning array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

```
var grossBrackets = new Array( '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000' );   
function bracketSort( itemToSort ) {
        for( index = 0 ; index < grossBrackets.length ; index++ ) {
            if ( itemToSort < grossBrackets[index] ) {
                bracketData[index]++;
            } else if ( itemToSort > grossBrackets[7] ) {
                grossBrackets[7]++;
            }
        }
        return bracketData;
    }
```

This is my current code, and I basically want to sort the data into their proper brackets. My source code is really long, but when I input these numbers into the function:

```
200.18
200.27
200.36
200.45
200.54
```

bracketData prints `5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5` or is there a better way to do this?

Brackets:
<300,
<400,
<500,
<600,
<700,
<800,
<900,
<1000,
greater than 1000

Comment: is `bracketData` a global variable, or should it be locally declared inside the function?

Comment: I left that part out, it's a global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want each item to be placed in one bracket, you need to end your loop over `grossBrackets` once you've found a match. You can do this with the `break` keyword, like so:

```
if ( itemToSort < grossBrackets[index] ) {
   bracketData[index]++;
   break;
}
```

Incidentally, you're checking whether `itemToSort` is greater than `grossBrackets[7]` 8 times, one for each element in `grossBrackets`. You really only need to do this once, so it doesn't need to be in the loop.

Comment: I understood everything except for the part where you said to take it out of the loop. How would you suggest to write it? Wouldn't I need to compare itemToSort with each element of the array to see which bracket it fits in?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are saying. I got it :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it was confusing because I said "less" when I meant "greater". Fixed.